# NAs introduced by coercion after removing NAs

Tags: r, na

I have to read from csv, where separator is ";" and decimal separator is ".". Also, NAs are NaN in the .csv. I am reading using

```
datos <- read.csv("googleplay.csv", sep=";", dec=".", na.strings=NaN)
```

Then, I am omitting NAs with

```
datos <- na.omit(datos)
```

I have checked with `colSums(is.na(datos))` that NAs doesn´t exist in my variable.
But anyways, when I execute `as.numeric(datos$Rating)` I get "NAs introduced by coercion", does anyone can tell me what is happening?

Comment: Consider `as.numeric("NA")` and `as.numeric("NaN")`.  Maybe you want `na.strings = c("NA", "NaN")`?  Perhaps take a second look at `?read.csv` ...

Comment: `na.omit` has nothing to do with knowing if a non-`NA` value can be converted to `numeric`. `na.omit("QUUX")` will not filter it out, but clearly it won't convert to a number. FYI, `na.omit(datos)` will remove the whole row whenever any `NA` is found in any column, not sure if that's the desired result.

Comment: Regardless, without seeing your actual data, we're unlikely to be able to tell you much more than this: something in your data is not number-like. Please [edit] your question and include the output from `head(grep("[^-0-9.]", datos$Rating, value=TRUE))`